# is there any similar function with clamp_ in tensorflow > 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, clamp

I'm converting torch code to tensorflow 2.0

```
prior_boxes = torch.FloatTensor(prior_boxes).to(device)  # (8732, 4)
prior_boxes.clamp_(0, 1)  # (8732, 4)
```

is there any replacement of clamp_(0,1) in tensorflow > 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Try [`tf.clip_by_value`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value), though unlike `clamp_`, it is not in-place:

```
t = tf.constant([[-10., -1., 0.], [0., 2., 10.]])
t2 = tf.clip_by_value(t, clip_value_min=-1, clip_value_max=1)
t2.numpy()
# gives [[-1., -1., 0.], [0., 1., 1.]]
```